# Unable to SUM from COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, divide-by-zero

I have produced a set of data using a countif as exampled below:

```
=COUNTIFS(Matrix!$C6:$EZ6,"1",Matrix!$C$5:$EZ$5,"Attainment",Matrix!$C$3:$EZ$3,AD$3)
```

What this is doing is looking at a students grades against a subject and calculating the count of that grade. I have 5 grades, *, 1, 2, 3, 4, so I have 5 sets of calculated columns for each subject. What I am now trying to do is a weighted sum using the results of these countif's. * = 0, 1=1,2=2 etc, however students can get more than 1 grade per subject so I need to average these.

Student X got two 2 grades for biology and one 3 grade, I need to do (2x2/2) + (1x3/3) = 2.3

I have tried

```
=SUM((F4*0)+(AG4*1/AG4)+(BH4*2/BH4)+(CI4*3/CI4)+(DJ4*4/DJ4))
```

However, I get a divide by zero error as not all cells hold a value above zero.

Is there a way to create a formula that says if the cell value is greater than zero then do the calculations, but if not ignore. I can't do a nested if. So, if the sum of AG4*1/AG4 results in a number then add this, but if it produces a zero, do not and move on and do the same for the next calculation. I can't do a nested if as more than one calculation may return a positive value.

Comment: Well, you have the logic as per your countifs(), so now use sumifs()...

Comment: Can you please give some mock example of your data as a table or picture... easier to understand your setup and how you have implemented your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your weighting formula seems wrong. You wrote '(2x2/2) + (1x3/3) = 2.3'. However, (2x2/2) + (1x3/3) returns 3.

Shouldn't it be (2x2) + (1x3) / (2+1) = 2.3 ?

Try using the following formula:

```
=(F4*0)+(AG4*1)+(BH4*2)+(CI4*3)+(DJ4*4) / SUM(F4,AG4,BH4,CI4,DJ4)
```

You can use wrap it in an IFERROR function to avoid errors for students with no grades